# Opening two files using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm new to python, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to open up multiple files using `argparse`. From the past questions posted here, it seems most people are asking to only open one file, which I used as the basis for my sample code. My sample code is:

```
import sys
import argparse 


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Compare two lists.")
parser.add_argument('infile1', type = file)
parser.add_argument('infile2', type = file) 
parser.add_argument('--same', help = 'Find those in List1 that are the same in List2')
parser.add_argument('--diff', help = 'Find those in List2 that do not exist in List2')
parser.parse_args()

data1 = set(l.rstrip() for l in open(infile1))
data2 = set(l2.rstrip() for l2 in open(infile2))
```

What is the correct way to use `argparse` over two text files? '-h' works as intended, but otherwise I get an error saying `error: argument --same: expected one argument`.

P.S. Eventually I will replace the two set commands to with/open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** The way you define `--same` and `--diff` they require an argument to follow them that would be assigned to the parsed arguments namespace. To make them boolean flags instead, you change that [action](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) by specifying the keyword argument `action='store_true'`:

```
parser.add_argument('--same',
                    help='Find those in List1 that are the same in List2',
                    action='store_true')
```

**2)** You don't store the parsed arguments in a variable, and you're trying to refer to them as locals instead of on the object returned by `parse_args()`:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.same:
   # ...
```

**3)** If you specify [`type=file`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type) for the argument, the parsed argument will actually already be an opened file object - so don't use `open()` on it:

```
data1 = set(l.rstrip() for l in args.infile1)
```

---

**Note**: Currently a user can legally specify both `--same` and `--diff`, so your program needs to deal with that. You'll probably want to make those flags [mutually exclusive](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

Comment: `argparse` provides a `FileType` class to use in place of `file` for the `type` parameter as well, which has two benefits: you can specify whether the file is opened for reading or writing, and you can use "-" as a synonym for standard input or standard output (depending in the file mode).

Comment: If you want to use `with... open`, don't use `FileType`.  Just accept a filename (string).  `FileType` is ok for simple script uses, but fails when file use is fancier.  There are a couple of Python bug_issues on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

because per default [`add_argument()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) is for an argument that takes a parameter (try `--help`), but you have to set [`action=store_true`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action).

```
parser.add_argument('--same', help = 'Find those in List1 that are the same in List2', action='store_true')
```

here's your `--help`:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--help'])
usage: [-h] [--same SAME] [--diff DIFF] infile1 infile2

Compare two lists.

positional arguments:
  infile1
  infile2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --same SAME  Find those in List1 that are the same in List2
  --diff DIFF  Find those in List2 that do not exist in List2
```

and once your arguments are parsed, you access them as members of args:

```
data1 = set(l.rstrip() for l in open(args.infile1))
data2 = set(l2.rstrip() for l2 in open(args.infile2))
```